# Can a closed curve be represented by a level set which is zero on the boundary, negative on the interior and positive otherwise?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, curves

Suppose we have a parameterisation of a simple closed curve $\mathcal{C}$.
Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{C}=\{x,y : f(x,y)=0\}$ and the interior and exterior of $\mathcal{C}$ are given by $\mathrm{in}(\mathcal{C})=\{x,y:f(x,y) < 0\}$ and $\mathrm{ex}(\mathcal{C})=\{x,y:f(x,y) > 0\}$ respectively?

Clearly if $\cal{C}$ is the unit circle, then such a function is given by $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2 - 1$.

Does such a function exist more generally? If so: proof? If not: why? Given a parameterisation $\gamma$ of $\mathcal{C}$, how could I construct $f$? I am happy to assume that $\gamma$ is analytic and has no cusps if necessary. Perhaps a homeo/diffeomorphism between $\cal{C}$ and the unit circle will help here.

Part of my motivation for asking is that I am currently working on software where I have to test if points are inside or outside (or on the boundary) of a closed region. This requires me to consider a line segment from my point of interest to infinity (or more practically a point known to be outside) and count the number of intersection points. Not only is this complex and slow, it also requires root finding to numerical precision in order to identify points very close to the boundary. However, if I am working with a circle then it is very easy. I simply test the sign of $x^2+y^2-1$ (or some translation/dilation of it).

**Edit:**

After the (good) answer by Steven, I should add: Given a parameterisation $\gamma$ of $\mathcal{C}$, how could I construct $f$ *without explicit knowledge of which points exist in the interior and which points exist in the exterior*. I say this as both his answers (continuous and not) for an arbitrary function require this information apriori and thus are not useful in testing whether or not a point is in the interior.

Comment: Just a quick note that I've (finally!) updated my answer to note how you can distinguish interior from exterior in the case where you implicitize to a polynomial function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there's a typo and that you want your $f$ to be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, not from the plane to itself. Also, presumably you want $f()$ to be continuous; otherwise the solution is trivial — take $f(\mathbf{x})=-1$ for $\mathbf{x}$ inside the curve, $f(\mathbf{x})=0$ for $\mathbf{x}$ on the curve, and $f(\mathbf{x})=1$ for $\mathbf{x}$ outside the curve. But even with continuity, it's pretty straightforward: let $g(\mathbf{x})$ be the unsigned minimum (you might need an infimum here but I don't think you should) distance from $\mathbb{x}$ to $\gamma$, and multiply $g()$ by the appropriate $\pm1$ inside/outside factor.

But better still, if your curve $\gamma$ is *rational* — that is to say, it can be expressed in the form $\gamma(t) = \langle \dfrac{p(t)}{r(t)},\dfrac{q(t)}{r(t)}\rangle$ for polynomial functions $p,q,r$ — then you can find a *polynomial* $f$ whose level set is the given curve. This process is known as *implicitization* of the parametric equation and you should be able to find details about it by passing those magic words into your favorite search engine; for instance [this summary of the process](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node68.html) for the case where the denominator $r()$ is just the unit function $r(t)=1$ and so the curve is $\gamma(t)=\langle p(t),q(t)\rangle$.

Note that in this latter case, it's also not too hard to determine inside vs. outside; just look at the leading x and y terms of your polynomial. Assuming that you have a 'clean' level set (that is, no infinite components to it) then these will both be even powers and they'll be either both positive or both negative. (Otherwise, there would be lines along which you can go to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ and therefore a curve between those lines where the zeroset itself goes to infinity.) If they're both positive, then the 'outside' component has to be the one in which $f(\mathbf{x})\gt 0$ and so the inside component is the one where $f(\mathbf{x})\lt 0$;  likewise if they're both negative then the inside component is the one where $f(\mathbf{x})\gt 0$.

Comment: "you should be able to find details about it by passing those magic words into your favorite search engine" - this is a remarkably general approach

Comment: I should note that from a computational point of view the resultant (pun intended) $f()$ can be quite complicated, and practically speaking you may well be better off with the root-finding than with trying to implicitize.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I've certainly found that helping people find the right magic words for their problem is a substantial part of the problem-solving.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger indeed, but one has to know to search for "implicitization of the parametric equation"

Comment: Yes that was a typo and I have rectified it (actually already had upon your posting). Your answer for a generic curve is good and I cannot criticise it. But its a bit disappointing that it doesn't actually help me at all with the code as it requires apriori knowledg of the interior points. However, your answer about rational curves could be very useful and I'll definitely check it out